# Parent-Child Window Interaction GWT

Tags: gwt

There is parent window, which has a Panel. When user clicks on a button from parent window then a popup opens up. On popup user populates some fields and clicks on OK button then a new row should be created on parent window's panel and set values from popup window and close it.

Any Idea how to do this in GWT? Please post some example if you have. Thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 0):

You must create a class representing the Popup and add a field to it referencing the Parent Window. In the constructor of the Popup, you pass the Parent Window as a parameter. When the user clicks ok in the popup, you call the PArent window and ask it to add a row via a method present in the ParentWindow

Comment: It is rather easy and would be better for you to implement it so you learn from your mistakes. If you still insist, I can't write a code until the weekend